# UV solder mask and dry film solder mask

Tags: pcb-fabrication, solder-mask

I am interested in masking my PCBs and I have a few questions about the process:

Using a dry film solder mask seems more straight-forward, but it is more expensive.

If I use UV solder mask in a syringe, I have seen that there are often problems when removing the transparent film. My question is, would it not be a good idea to use a laminator or an oven to heat the UV solder mask, before exposing it to UV?

Would that help to prevent it from coming off together with the transparent film (since that is the process that is followed with dry film solder mask as well, in order to achieve good adhesion)?

Any help?